# How should I create elevated Users in PHP, MySQL, and Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, oop

I have a PHP `User` object that can become a different object by extending the previous object, which is basically an abstraction of the database. Here's a visualization:

```
                  ┌─ Parent
     ┌─ Client ───┤
     │            └─ Student
User ┤
     │            ┌─ Teacher
     └─ Employee ─┤
                  └─ Staff
```

My `Users` table contains basic user info, and the `Client` table includes the `User.user_id` plus some extra info that all clients would have, and it cascades downward.

Anyway, I'm trying to come up with the best way of creating the `User`, (or `Teacher`) object. I'm wondering which of these is best, or if none of them are. Here's what I'm considering:

#### 1. Each object creates itself

My `Teacher->create()` method would call `parent::create()` cascading down to root User object. This would work, except I would need each preceding ID. To create the `Teacher` I need the `Client.client_id` and to create the `Client` I need the `User.user_id`.

#### 2. The model creates the objects

Maybe my `Users` model creates the objects using a switch comparing the `get_class($user)` function? Something like:

```
$userType = get_class($user);
switch($userType){
    case 'Student':
        // creates user row, client row, and student row
        createStudent($user); break;
    case 'Parent':
        // creates user row, client row, and parent row
        createParent($user); break;
    case 'Client': 
        // creates user row and client row
        createClient($user); break;
    case 'User':
        // creates user row
        createUser($user); break;
    // few more times for the employee branch
}
```

This could work, but I'd love to cascade the actions down but I can't seem to wrap my head around how it would work, since I need to first create the `User` object and get the `User.user_id` before I can create the `Client`, etc.

Could I use a `switch` statement with the same `case` multiple times? Like this:

```
createUser($user); // create user 1st (ty Svetlio)
switch($userType){
    case 'Student':
    case 'Parent':
    case 'Client':
        createClient($user); // create client 2nd
    case 'Student':
        createStudent($user); // create student 3rd
        break;
    case 'Parent':
        createParent($user); // or create parent 3rd
        break;
}
```

Except, in the first cases, wouldn't `'Parent'` call `createClient()` AND `createStudent()`? And can I even enter mulitple `'Student'` cases like I'm doing here?

Is there a standard method of doing this that I'm missing?

Thanks a lot for reading!

Comment: For switch check documentation > http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php There is multiple case support :)  but never set default at first position :) default must be always last.. and there must be BREAK at each case end..

Comment: I know default is usually at the end, but since I need to create the User first, I was hoping I could use default to my advantage by forcing it to happen first, somehow. Hrm

Comment: if you need it always set it before the SWITCH ...
inside the switch you must put only actions depending on the switch check, nothing else..

Comment: oh durr that makes sense, haha. Thanks, i'll edit it to move it outside the switch

Comment: why don't you just use roles? A user with roles employee & teacher ? then you can just test using `isTeacher()` fn (or similar) ? This seems overly complex

Comment: Well, because more specific user types will have additional information. So a client will have a bit more info than a user. I could fold them all into one large row in users then add roles in a separate table, but having all that info in one row seems.. not-ideal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I decided to do was have the Model create each user.